# Unable to Locate Connected HID Devices Using HidLibrary

Tags: .net, usb, hid

Using the HidLibrary DLL found on GitHub, but can't locate any connected HID devices on my WIN10 machine. Always returns device list length of zero. I've tried multiple vendor IDs, PIDs, for actual connected devices (mouse, touchscreen, etc). HidDeviceList always comes back with a length of 0.

```
Imports HIDLibrary
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Dim HidDeviceList As HIDLibrary.HidDevice()
Dim MyDevice As HidDevice
Dim DevDetected As Boolean

Private Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click

    Try

        HidDeviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(&H3F0) 'My HP wireless mouse
        If HidDeviceList.Length > 0 Then
            MyDevice = HidDeviceList(0)
            DevDetected = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayException(Me.Name, ex)
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```